# An R function to work out the preceding value

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a table of staff, who they report to and what level they are.

I've been working with a similar table, and @TonakShah was kind enough to help me with calculating the lowest level location is and the level above is using the solution below.

My employee table looks like this:

```
input = structure(list(Level.1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = "Board", class = "factor"), Level.2 = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Aasha", "Grace", "Marisol"
), class = "factor"), Level.3 = structure(c(4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("Alex", "Chandler", "Millie", "Tushad"), class = "factor"), 
    Level.4 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("#", 
    "Frank", "Joey", "Rachel", "Sarah", "Tony"), class = "factor"), 
    Level.5 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("#", 
    "Lela", "Millie", "Ross"), class = "factor"), Level.6 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "#", class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

and using the technique described here by Ronak (stackoverflow.com/questions/56903188/create-a-table-from-a-hierarchy/)
which is,

```
as.data.frame(t(apply(input, 1, function(x) 
       {new_x = x[x != "###"]; c(rev(tail(new_x, 2)), length(new_x)) })))
```

I can get most of the required table.  But I'm having trouble trying to get "the bosses" (eg. those with employees but are not "the board").

My ideal output would look something like this (I've added colnames to make it easier to understand):

```
structure(list(Subordinate = structure(c(9L, 4L, 14L, 5L, 7L, 
13L, 9L, 2L, 1L, 12L, 11L, 6L, 3L, 8L, 10L), .Label = c("Aasha", 
"Alex", "Chandler", "Frank", "Grace", "Joey", "Lela", "Marisol", 
"Millie", "Rachel", "Ross", "Sarah", "Tony", "Tushad"), class = "factor"), 
    Boss = structure(c(5L, 10L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
    7L, 4L, 8L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("Aasha", "Alex", "Board", 
    "Chandler", "Frank", "Grace", "Joey", "Marisol", "Millie", 
    "Tushad"), class = "factor"), Level = c(5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 
    4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

I think I maybe do it with a loop, but this doesn't seem to be the best answer.  Can anyone offer any other tips?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't come up with a prettier solution but this works. Using a `while` loop in the `apply` call used previously, we can do

```
output <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, apply(input, 1, function(x) {
   new_x = as.character(x[x != "#"])
   list_df <- list()
   i = 1
   while(length(new_x) >= 2) {
      #Get last 2 eneteries
      list_df[[i]] <- c(rev(tail(new_x, 2)), length(new_x))
      #Go one level deeper
      new_x = head(new_x, -1)
      i  = i +1
   }
   do.call(rbind, list_df)
}))

#To remove duplicate enteries
output[!duplicated(output), ]

#         V1       V2 V3
#1    Millie    Frank  5
#2     Frank   Tushad  4
#3    Tushad    Grace  3
#4     Grace    Board  2
#5      Lela    Frank  5
#9      Tony   Millie  4
#10   Millie    Grace  3
#12     Alex    Aasha  3
#13    Aasha    Board  2
#14    Sarah     Alex  4
#17     Ross     Joey  5
#18     Joey Chandler  4
#19 Chandler  Marisol  3
#20  Marisol    Board  2
#21   Rachel Chandler  4
```